# How to handle HTML Audio element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I want to click on the play button of audio element in the browser

[image]

Now the html tags for the audio element are:

```
<audio autoplay="true" controls="" controlslist="nodownload" id="audioElement" style="visibility: visible;" src="file.wav">
            <source type="audio/x-wav" src="">
</audio>
```

Using Selenium, I can click on the audio element using:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("audioElement")).click();
```

But how do I specifically click on the play and volume buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call JavaScript native method to play the audio:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#audioElement').play();");
```

or you can set volume value:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#audioElement').volume = 0.3;");
```

To mute audio:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('#audioElement').muted = true;");
```

You can check [list of all `audio` properties and methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp)

*Update*

To get current state (paused, muted, volume level...):

```
jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#audioElement').muted");
jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#audioElement').paused");
jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#audioElement').volume");
```

Comment: Hi. How can I verify whether the audio is played, paused or muted?